# problem loading data into R

Tags: r, dataset

I have problem with loading data into R:

```
fileUrl <- "http://jadi.net/files/iran_it_status_1394_detail_data_jadi_net.tsv"

download.file(fileUrl , destfile="iran_it_status_1394_detail_data_jadi_net.tsv")

dev <- read.delim("iran_it_status_1394_detail_data_jadi_net.tsv",
              header=TRUE,sep="\t",blank.lines.skip = TRUE,
              na.strings="",fileEncoding="UTF-8",
              stringsAsFactors=FALSE,skipNul = TRUE)
```

I receive the following error:

```
Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  : 
  no lines available in input
  In addition: Warning message:
  In read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  :
  invalid input found on input connection    'iran_it_status_1394_detail_data_jadi_net.tsv'
```

Edit: The dataset has 1217 rows and 33 variables.

```
names(data) <- c("timestamp","age","sex","birth_province","work_province","experience","education",
            "certificate","learn","project","book","language","wish_language","db","desktop_os",
            "wish_os","mobile","env","theme","src_ctrl","tab_space","drink","items","device","title",
            "org_type","org_emp","income","perk","job_contract","job_type","hour_wage","happy")
```

for language variable I expect this output:

```
data[1:3,"language"]
```

C#, Javascript, R, SQL

Java, C#, Javascript, Objective C, Swift, SQL

C#, SQL

Python Solutions are also welcome

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a simple R problem and not data science enough.

Comment: Tough one; since R is so commonly used in data science, I could imagine some basic R questions being OK here, even if they might be somewhat better on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @SeanOwen Useful criterion: If it might be useful to non data-science R users, it should go in Stack Overflow. There's not a single byte of data science in this question. Any R user might want to read a data file like this in. Hence close, move to stack overflow.

Comment: Are there non-data-science R users? anything you'd do with R seems like part of data science to me. I think this is more on-topic for SO, but that's different from blocking it here. Some SEs overlap. People have to do stuff like this to do their data science work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am able to load the data set like so:

```
 dev <- read.table("iran_it_status_1394_detail_data_jadi_net.tsv",
                   header=TRUE, sep="\t", blank.lines.skip = TRUE,
                   na.strings="",
                   stringsAsFactors=FALSE, skipNul = TRUE, fill=T, quote="")
```

Note the removal of the encoding (so that the function "finds" lines in the file), the fill attribute (to allow for a ragged table with empty cells), and the elimination of quotes (apparently there is a misquoted line somewhere near line 585).

This results in a table full of encoded characters - you'll need to know more about the source data to figure out how to work with it, but if you open the file up in a raw text editor (e.g.: Sublime text) you might get some clues:

[image: Character encoding issues?]

Comment: Please see my edit.

Comment: Yes, when using the `read.table()` call above I get 1217 observations of 33 variables

Comment: The data is loaded by your script but there is a problem with one of my text variables: language . see my edit.

Comment: It doesn't necessarily solve the character encoding issues, but I realized that "#" is the default comment character; comment processing should be ignored:
`dev <- read.table("iran_it_status_1394_detail_data_jadi_net.tsv",
                   header=TRUE, sep="\t",
                   na.strings="", encoding="UTF-8",
                   stringsAsFactors=FALSE, skipNul = TRUE, fill=T, quote="", comment.char="")`

Comment: You are right. Now C# is read correctly but there are extra \" at the beginning and the end of my strings.

Comment: Those are escaped quotes; if you remove the `quote` parameter from `read.table` above it would eliminate those - except for the fact that the data contain mismatched quotes somewhere in the document and will fail without it.  Again, there is probably a solve with respect to encoding.

Answer (score -1):

Try using either`try` or `tryCatch`:

See here `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13613270/how-to-fix-the-error-in-r-of-no-lines-available-in-input`

Comment: I don't know how to integrate it with my code.